# How to change the owner name in a Google Play signing key?

Tags: google-play

I know that some things in a signing key (like the validity period) can't be changed. Can the owner name change? If yes, how can I do it using `keytool`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Interesting question. I've done a bit of digging, and it seems like it isn't possible. See [this detailed answer](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/148074/java-keytool-how-to-modify-a-keystores-owner-and-issuer-information) on the security stack exchange. While you (and I) often think of certificate as just a public key, the certificate is the public key combined with the owner (Distinguished-Name) information, and the certificate hash is a hash of this information. So if you change the Owner information, you change the certificate, and so change the certificate hash. This is true for both APK Signing V1 and [V2](https://source.android.com/security/apksigning/v2).